# TIE fighter's destruction of the Finalizer Star Destroyer's turbolasers

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Finn and Poe disable I recall 2 turbolaser batteries during their escape from the First Order Star Destroyer [*Finalizer*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Finalizer). A *Finalizer* officer describes that they have lost their turbolasers. According to Wookieepedia the *Finalizer* has 3000 turbolasers, not 2. Even if that's a typo, I would expect a ship of that size to mount at least 300 turbolasers.

Is there any explanation anyone is aware of for this?

Comment: “Even if that's a typo” — *[shouts excitedly at the sky]* that’s one *hell* of a typo!

Comment: Presumably the officer was only referring to the turbolasers that were actively targeting the TIE fighter, not all the ships' turbolasers.

Answer (score 3):

During the escape from the Star Destroyer, Poe tells Finn that they will need to disable "**at least a few** of those turbolasers" to make their escape. They proceed to blow up the turrets immediately ahead of them. Hux then decides to use the ventral cannons instead.

It's obvious from Poe's remark that they weren't trying to destroy all of the weapons on the Finalizer; they only wanted to blow up the ones that were a direct threat. (It's also possible that more than 2 were blown up during the escape, we just didn't see all of them.)

So, the explanation is that Poe/Finn didn't blow up all 3000 turbo lasers, but they did blow up the ones positioned in such a way as to shoot down the TIE fighter, leaving Hux to resort to the secondary weapons instead.